# How to send parameters to "Open in Cloud Shell" URL?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I want to create a button that will open GCP cloud shell and run code that create some resources in the account.
I am trying to use "Open in Cloud Shell" (https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/open-in-cloud-shell) URL and adding my GIT repo to the URL, but the problem is that my code should get different arguments in every run. **There is a way to send arguments with this URL? Or maybe there is another solution for running code with arguments in GCP cloud shell via URL?**

Comment: Can we drill into the puzzle a bit more?  I normally think of Cloud Shell as being very interactive;.  If what you want to do is have "code run" that works with GCP when a REST call is made, this sounds very much like Cloud Run.  Have you considered Cloud Run for your solution as opposed to Cloud Shell?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.
Cloud Run seems less relevant for me because the code runs in a specific account, am I right? 
To be more clear - I need the code to run in the user account. The code is a set of commands that build resources in the user account. So I need to run the code when the user clicks the URL and I want to allow him to send specific parameters.  For example, I want to run this line: 'gcloud pubsub topics..."$Name"' for creating a topic (I want to allow to choose the topic name - so I need to add a parameter to the URL or send this parameter in another way).

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT a direct answer to your original question however it might be useful for an overall answer.  If we don't like this answer, simply let me know and we'll delete it.

From you clarification in the comments, what I now sense is that you want to create GCP resources that the user can work with.  For example, a PubSub topic.  We'll use that as an illustration.  The first thing I want to do is disavow us of the notion that there is anything "special" about a resource and the identity that it used to create that resource other than the identity must have authority to create it.  For example, if user "john" creates a topic, that doesn't mean that the topic is "owned" by john.  A GCP resource "just exists" after it is created.  In order for a user to "use" a resource, it (the resource) must authorize the sets of users to work with it.  This is where GCP [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam) comes into play.  Separate your goal into two parts.

1. Upon request, a new GCP topic is created
2. Once the GCP topic is created, you grant permissions on the topic to be worked with by named identities (users/groups)

Don't think "The user who creates the topic is immediately the one who can work with it".

For example, you may wish to grant your users the ability to subscribe to a topic but may not want those users to be able to "manipulate" topics such as creation/update/delete.

I am assuming that the solution you are working against is for end users rather than internal developers?

Off the top of my head, I'm tempted to suggest that you review the following very short video:

[How to authenticate calls to your Google Cloud Run service](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5r21CVd6nwo)

This is just a teaser but it does give us a clue.  It alludes to the notion that a request from an authenticated (to Google) user can be received by a Cloud Run instance and Cloud Run can then know who the user is.  With that in mind, in the code of your Cloud Run, you can then make a "yes/no" decision as to whether to proceed.  If yes to proceed, then Cloud Run (which is indeed running as a single user and we won't change that) creates the topic and then assigns subscription (or publication or other) permissions to the topic on behalf of the identity that came in with the request.